# Alternatives to Matplotlib TextBox widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, textbox

I want to use an input field with my pyplot, basically what the textbox widget would be perfect for. The problem is that there seems to be a bug with the setup I have and basically every time the user clicks into the field they have to press `[TAB]` once before the input is registered. I'm pretty sure it's not my code's problem but a compatibility bug in the library or something, because the issue also arises with the super simple demo code below or the example given [here](https://www.demo2s.com/python/python-matplotlib-widgets-textbox.html). My code even works normally on my private laptop, which is unix based though.

Are there any alternatives to the existing TextBox widget? If so, can I easily incorporate them in my plots?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox


def submit(text):
    print(text)


axbox = plt.axes([0.4, 0.05, 0.3, 0.075])
text_box = TextBox(axbox, '')
text_box.on_submit(submit)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The linked code is not an "official example". The matplotlib docs are [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html?highlight=widgets%20textbox). No idea what `demo2s` is.

Comment: You are right, I deleted that word in the question.

Comment: Have you checked that the matplotlib versions are comparable between the two machines?

Comment: No, I will do that tonight. But since it's such a simple use of the function I think it's unlikely that that's the problem to be honest. It should be compatible with every release version since the feature was introduced.